# object defined error with assigning named range to array

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying t assign the values of a named range to an array of variants. I get an application or object defined error almost at the level of assignment code 
    Material = ThisWorkbook.Names("RMInStoreName").RefersToRange
i got this example from [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=92426) and have used it before sucessfully.

I am still trying to figure out why this error is showing up, i seem to have run out of ideas, anybody can help me point in the right direction will realy save me alot
The code is below
Here is the code

```
 Sub MonitorStore()
Dim ThreshHold As Variant, InStore As Variant, StatusReport As Variant
Dim Material As Variant    'is the name of the material
Status As Variant
'status is a variable which holds data on wether the user  has seen msg and 
'wants to     supress msg
'the ThreshHold is the minimum allowed in store below which messages are firerd
'InStore is the volume of materials currently in store
'and be told of another error after solving error one, report all at once


 Material = ThisWorkbook.Names("RMInStoreName").RefersToRange
ThreshHold = ThisWorkbook.Names("RMThreshHold").RefersToRange
InStore = ThisWorkbook.Names("RMInStore").RefersToRange
Status = ThisWorkbook.Names("RMStatus").RefersToRange

'other code.............
'dont expect error from unexecuted code
End Sub
```

Thanks for help
Stephen

Comment: Your code snippet won't compile. You need a `Dim` in front of `Status`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you don't have all of the named ranges defined in the workbook.

You can verify the named ranges using the Formula tab.

Formula --> Name Manager

[image]

Answer (score 0):

RefersToRange will return a range object.  Its the value you are after then:

```
Material = ThisWorkbook.Names("RMInStoreName").RefersToRange.Value
```

or you can use:

```
Material = Evaluate("RMInStoreName")
```

or:

```
Material = Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names("RMInStoreName").RefersTo).Value
```